# How to mix material and texture to single mesh?

Tags: materials, image

I'm making a ceramic plate and on the top surface I want to show a painting of flowers which I have in .png format. The ceramic texture is on top and I added a new texture layer below it. I have selected some faces and assigned it to the vertex group. Then I added a texture to the material, I get the image, but it's showing a black background on it. I added a transparent shader.

Is my method correct? Why am I getting this black background with the .png transparent image?

[image: screenshots of nodes]

[image]

[image: screenshot of problem]

Comment: You don't need a transparent shader. Read : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447

Comment: @cegaton i tried the below 2 answer but the image is not clear http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=6c7605bbba11a27c9630255c70b4433c

Comment: again, you don't need a transparent shader, you need to use the alpha channel to control the mix of two shaders or two colors. Please read the link on the comments. https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8ZkZ.png

Comment: @cegaton yes the 2nd node help me Thanks

Comment: The issue is to stop thinking of the textures as transparent but to think in terms of masks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can only mix textures/materials in one "material".
Try this:

1. Assigne all verts to "Material.001"
2. Copy "Material.004" and add it to "Material.001"
3. UV unwrap your object
4. Copy nodes (see the image below)
5. Set "image texture" to clip and to non-color data
6. Match UV Unwrap to your texture

[image: Result]

[image: Material node setup]

[image: UV unwrap]

Comment: 1 Question why the image is not clear look blur or mix with it. Rest everything is fine

Comment: painting is not clear on the plate. http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=bb18790d8b3d94a6f6bfb534dd366a8c

Answer (score 0):

thats because you take the alpha information of a colored texture. even if you select "non color data" its just a gray picture. Alpha  need to be 100% white

1. download that white texture that i linked
2. replace it with your alpha texture
3. add difuse bsdf for your colored texture

try with this black and white texture [image: enter you cant see it... but its there xD]

[image: new node setup]

Comment: Still the same its not clear on the plate